# What are the returned parameters for the PayPal Success Return

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am integrating PayPal Payments blind, this means I have no means to test, I've researched this more than a lot of times, and I can't seem to find any information about this.

When my client successfully pays me (integrated using REST API), and they are returned to the specified return URL, what are the exact parameters returned, primarily, what are the parameter keys for the Payment ID and the Payer ID.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> I am integrating PayPal Payments blind, this means I have no means to test

This doesn't make any sense; you should fully test your integration as you develop it, using the PayPal sandbox environment.

Redirecting away from your site is an old way to integrate PayPal, used by old websites. Current integrations do not use any redirects. At all.

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I know how to accept payments, I just don't have a paypal account and I refuse to make one for privacy reasons, I simply want to know what the URL Parameters are for the Payment ID and the Payer ID once a user has authorized a payment and is redirected to my return URL.